# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a list in the for loop.

**Here is my code**
I created a property here

```
    public class SampleItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add value from another list

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItem = new List<SampleItem>(); // Error: Index out of range
 for (int i = 0; i < otherListItem.Count; i++)
 {
      sampleItem[i].Id = otherListItem[i].Id;
      sampleItem[i].StringValue = otherListItem[i].Name;
 }
```

Can someone correct my code please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get an index out of range because you're referring to `sampleItem[i]` when `sampleItem` has no items. You must [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) items...

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItem = new List<SampleItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < otherListItem.Count; i++)
{
    sampleItem.Add(new SampleItem { 
        Id = otherListItem[i].Id, 
        StringValue = otherListItem[i].Name 
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks guys. Only a minute and I got 8 response! This is why I love this place! I tried it and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItem = new List<SampleItem>(); // Error: Index out of range
for (int i = 0; i < otherListItem.Count; i++)
{
     sampleItem.Add(new sampleItem()); // add this line
     sampleItem[i].Id = otherListItem[i].Id;
     sampleItem[i].StringValue = otherListItem[i].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `List` must be `Add`ed to; you can't just set its indexed items to values if they haven't been created yet.  You need something like:

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItems = new List<SampleItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < otherListItem.Count; i++)
{
    SampleItem si = new SampleItem
    {
        Id = otherListItem[i].Id,
        StringValue = otherListItem[i].Name
    };
    sampleItems.Add(si);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItem = new List<SampleItem>();
foreach( var item in otherListItem)
{
 sampleItem.Add(new SampleItem { Id = item.Id, StringValue = item.Name});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop try replacing what you have with something like this:

```
SampleItem item;
item.Id = otherListItem[i].Id;
item.StringValue = otherListItem[i].StringValue;
sampleItem.add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItem = (from x in otherListItem select new SampleItem { Id = x.Id, StringValue = x.Name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

do following:

```
List<SampleItem> sampleItem = new List<SampleItem>();
 for (int i = 0; i < otherListItem.Count; i++)
 {
      sampleItem.Add(new SampleItem {Id= otherListItem[i].Id, StringValue=otherListItem[i].Name});

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you get the error as you never add any items to the sampleItem list.

a better way of doing this would be using Linq (untested)

```
var sampleItem =  otherListItem.Select(i => new SampleItem { Id= i.Id, StringValue = i.Name}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

//using system.linq;

```
otherListItem.ToList().Foreach(item=>{
  sampleItem.Add(new sampleItem{
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because I had mapped a column two times in Mapper class.
In my case i was simply assigning list elements.
e.g.

```
itemList item;
ProductList product;
item.name=product.name;
item.price=product.price;
```